# Angular 7 formbuilder initialize value on multi-select get form invalid

Tags: angular, validation, formbuilder

I have problem initializing a fromgroup with select multiple control.
the initialization runs ok, but angular mark the from as invalid.

```
{{controlPanelForm.value | json}} -> tasks: ["3","1","5"]
{{controlPanelForm.status | json}} -> "INVALID"
```

now, when user select one or more tasks on multi-select the formgroup become valid.

```
{{controlPanelForm.value | json}} -> tasks: ["3","1","5"]
{{controlPanelForm.status | json}} -> "VALID"
```

I need, the formGroup valid from the initialization.
thanks, in advance.
////html

```
<form [formGroup]="controlPanelForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <select multiple id="tasks" size="7" [formControl]="controlPanelForm.get('tasks')">
        <option *ngFor="let t of projectTasks" [ngValue]="t.id">{{t.title}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div>
    {{controlPanelForm.value | json}}
</div>
<div>
    {{controlPanelForm.status | json}}
</div>
```

/////ts

```
controlPanelForm: FormGroup;
projectTasks: ProjectTask[] =[
    {id:'3', title:'title3'},
    {id:'1', title:'title1'},
    {id:'5', title:'title5'},
]
projectTasksIds: string[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.projectTasks.map((t) => {
        this.projectTasksIds.push(t.id.toString());
    });
    this.buildForm();
}

buildForm(): void {
        this.controlPanelForm = this.fb.group({
            'tasks': [[this.projectTasksIds], Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.+')])],
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was syncro! the values of tasks: ["3","1","5"] came from ajax. So, when the form initilize the values are: []. To solve problem, I used controlPanelForm.patchValues(...) method on ajax response.
I hope this be helpfull for the others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is defined with

```
'tasks': [[this.projectTasksIds], ...
```

This means that once requested, your value becomes

```
form.tasks = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

But that's not the issue (altough you should correct it). The issue is that you have this data

```
projectTasks: ProjectTask[] =[
    {id:'3', title:'title3'},
    {id:'1', title:'title1'},
    {id:'5', title:'title5'},
]
```

And you iterate over this

```
this.projectTasks.tasks.map(...)
```

It doesn't exist ! this means your array is empty, so your value is empty.

Comment: Sorry, trichetriche. the problem was copy/paste.  this.projectTasks.map(...) now is correct. Please check again. Thanks